# Pass variables from one function to another in the same Controller

Tags: php, laravel

This is my controller and the function for displaying the view. At the moment I have to repeat all the variables from index to exportPDF. And thus, exporting takes too much time.

```
class MyController extends Controller {
    public function index($id) {
        $article = Article::find($id);
        return view('articles', compact('article');
    }
}
```

And the other method which actually exports the pdf. I want it to be shorter and more simple like this:

```
public function exportPDF($id) {
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('articles', ['article' => $article]);
    return $pdf->setPaper('a4')->setOrientation('portrait')->setOption('margin-top', 0)->download('export-' . $id . '.pdf');
}
```

How can I pass this `$article` variable from index to exportPDF function? Btw. the route in web.php (Laravel 5.3) is set up like:

```
Route::get('exportPDF/{id}', 'MyController@exportPDF');
```

Comment: Are they in the same class? so `$this->exportPDF()` should work no? if the exportPDF method is in another class `PdfGenerator` for example, then `(new PdfGenerator)->exportPDF(...)` should work

Comment: Yes, they are in the same controller. But I'm not sure if I understand you well. I want the page to be exported to PDF when button is clicked (which calls /exportPDF url). So, I need those variables from the index function also to be in the exportPDF. It works when I copy all variables and paste it to exportPDF. But it looks ugly and takes too much time to export the pdf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use it similar like code below

```
class MyController extends Controller{
    public function index($id){
        $article = Article::find($id);
        $exportedPDF = $this->exportPDF($id,$article);
        return view('articles', compact('article');
    }

    public function exportPDF($id,$article){
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('articles', ['article' => $article]);
        return $pdf->setPaper('a4')->setOrientation('portrait')->setOption('margin-top', 0)->download('export-' . $id . '.pdf');
    }
}
```

Comment: When I do this, I'm getting this error `Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\MyController::exportPDF()`. Btw I've changed my route to be `/exportPDF/`

Comment: I'v changed also function index and function export PDF, so copy/paste them both and then try. If you don't need `$id` anymore remove it.

Comment: Nope, not working. Btw. I'm having more variables to pass (17 of them). Can I pass that `$exportedPDF` variable  to exportPDF function as array argument?

Comment: Tell me how you pass those variables? And where do you get them? From view by `$request` or from `Controller`?

Comment: I'm creating them in `function index()`. Passing them to 'articles' view. And in that view I have a button which leads to `/exportPDF` which is using `function exportPDF()`. It works only when I copy all variables from `index()` to `exportPDF()`

Comment: Ok. It works now when I add this to the `exportPDF()`... `$test = $this->index($article)`, and then `$pdf = PDF::loadView(['articles', 'article' => $article]); ` ... But the problem is it still takes too much time to export one page.